# How can I stop a dishwasher water supply from causing the tap water to smell?

Tags: water, dishwasher, smell, hose, taps

OK, here is the situation:

I recently bought a dishwasher that has a shorter water hose than required. So I bought this [inlet hose](http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/red-inlet-hose---25m-264039)
and connected the two hoses using this [inlet connector](http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/inlet-hose-connector-241109).

For water supply I used a [self cutting tap](http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/self-cutting-appliance-tap---15mm-315361).

The problem is, when dishwasher tap is open (dishwasher not working), and I open the main drinking water tap, my water has strange smell and taste. (This is not the case when the dishwasher tap is closed or the dishwasher hose is connected to tap without extension).

The only cause I could conclude from this is that the water flows back from inlet hose into the drinking tap, giving it the odor and taste. (although I can't tell the inlet hose smells by sniffing!)

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I already tried returning the inlet hose and trying another one (maybe that particular one had issue) -- but no success.

### update:

Today I came up across this [shower check valve](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Taps+Showers/d240/Shower+Valves/sd3000/Shower+Check+Valve+15mm+x+1+2+/p87136). Do you guys think this can prevent the backflow of water if I install it on my dishwasher tap?

Answer (score 1):

A check valve will surely prevent water from flowing backwards, as that's exactly what it's designed to do.

In case you're not familiar with them, the arrow points in the direction of flow. So whichever way you want the water to flow, point the arrow in that direction.

Comment: Thanks! It's reassuring to to see you also think check valve would work in this case. I will have to buy it and give it a god. Will update you here on the outcome :)

Comment: Update: that part didn't fit the tap as the end screw is designed for a much smaller connection, and so far I have failed to find one that does fit :(